# javascript: best way of checking if object has a certain element or property?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, undefined

Suppose I have this:

```js
var person = { "name": "John Doe", "email": "john.doe@example.com" };
```

This object only has two elements called `name` and `email`. Some persons also have an element `age`, but this particular person doesn't. What's the best way to check this?

- `if (person.age) { ... }`
- `if (person.age != undefined) { ... }`
- `if (person.age !== undefined) { ... }`
- `if (typeof(person.age) != 'undefined') { ... }`
- `if (person.hasOwnProperty('age')) { ... }`

I know all these don't do the same, e.g. `if (person.age)` would also fail if `age` *does* exist but it's `false` or `null` or `''` or `0`. And I wonder if some aren't just flat out wrong.

Note that `person` is known to be an existing object here, but `person.age` may or may not exist.

Comment: to me `person.hasOwnProperty('age')` :) _value_ of the property is a different thing!

Comment: So what do you want to check for exactly? That the property exists? "*has a certain value*", as in your question title, would be completely different thing.

Comment: I guess `if (typeof person.age == "number")` is what you'll be looking for.

Comment: @Bergi right, that was confusing, I changed 'value' to 'element' in the title. Yes I meant just to check if the property exists.

Comment: @RocketNuts Then use `hasOwnProperty` or `in` (depending on whether you care if it's an *own* property or not). If you also care about the type of the property, use `typeof`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's check the reliability of these ways of checking if object has a certain element or property:

This can fail if `Boolean(person.age)` is `false`

```
if (person.age) { ... }
```

This can fail if `person.age` is `null` or `undefined`

```
if (person.age != undefined) { ... }
```

These can fail if `person.age` is `undefined`

```
if (person.age !== undefined) { ... }
if (typeof(person.age) != 'undefined') { ... }
```

On the other hand, the **hasOwnProperty()** method returns a `boolean` indicating *whether the object has the specified property as own (not inherited) property*. So It does not depend on the value of `person.age` property. So it is the best way here

```
if (person.hasOwnProperty('age')) { ... }
```

If you want to go further and check if an object has a property on it that is iterable(all properties including own properties as well as the inherited ones) then using `for..in` loop will give you the desired result.

Answer (score -3):

You could use `Object.hasOwnProperty()`. Check out documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Comment: The OP knows that already, it's in his list of options. **Why** should he use `hasOwnProperty`?

Answer (score -3):

You can use hasOwnProperty to check particular key or property present or not.

```
var person = { "name": "John Doe", "email": "john.doe@example.com" };
console.log(person.hasOwnProperty('age')) //false

var person = { "name": "John Doe", "email": "john.doe@example.com", "age": 18 };
console.log(person.hasOwnProperty('age')) //true
```

if you use  (person.age) it will give you false if the value is false or empty or null even the age property is present and has own property check property is present or not

Comment: The OP knows that already, it's in his list of options. **Why** should he use `hasOwnProperty`?

Comment: I saw the edit, but am still missing the explanation.