# Why do i not get a key if it is false in my object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function which takes the data from a post of user and creates an email object. To make sure i dont get errors i check if the values exist before i try to assign them to new object. I have a few keys which are Boolean like dflt and bounce.

```
 const createEmail = async(element) =>{
            var newEmail = new contacts.typedEmailAddress
            if(element.id == null){
                newEmail.id = uuidv4()
            }
            else
            {
                newEmail.id = element.id  
            }
                    console.log('Value of Bounce: '+ element.bounce)
                    newEmail.type = element.type
                    newEmail.address = element.address
                    if (element.name){
                        newEmail.name = element.name
                        }
                    if (element.otherLabel){
                        newEmail.otherLabel = element.otherLabel
                        }
                    if (element.dflt){
                        newEmail.dflt = element.dflt
                        }
                    if (element.source){
                        newEmail.source = element.source
                    }
                    if (element.bounce){
                        newEmail.bounce = element.bounce
                    }
                    if (element.dnmm){
                        newEmail.dnmm = element.dnmm
                    }

            console.log(JSON.stringify(newEmail))
    return newEmail

    }
```

when i pass to the above code the flowing element

```
{ id: '99a8da99-4ea9-4c96-92ee-c98571b133b9',
  parentId: 'farm::03590B5F-AC65-45CB-BB87-C53C2EBCE8B9',
  type: 'default',
  address: 'reza@test.com',
  name: 'reza@test.com',
  otherLabel: null,
  dflt: true,
  dnmm: true,
  bounce: false,
  source: 'Intelius' }
```

here is what i get out

```
Value of Bounce: false
{"id":"99a8da99-4ea9-4c96-92ee-c98571b133b9","address":"reza@test.com","name":"reza@test.com","type":"default","dflt":true,"source":"Intelius","dnmm":true}
```

for index reasons i need the key either to be true or false but not sure why on false it isn't created

Comment: Use `if ("bounce" in element)` instead of `if (element.bounce)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript: best way of checking if object has a certain element or property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425072/javascript-best-way-of-checking-if-object-has-a-certain-element-or-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking on `element.bounce` in the condition before setting `newEmail.bounce`.

Essentially

```
if (false) {
   // Add property
}
```

You might want to do `element.bounce !== undefined`.

Comment: So basically when using if (element.bounce) it will not return value if false only if the set value is true.

Comment: Look at from the if statement from a logical standpoint, and not as values. You are asking "If `element.bounce` is true then add the property". If `element.bounce` has the value `false´, the condition will fail, and no property will be added.

Answer (score -2):

Just delete the if before assign the property bounce.

`if(bounce)` is the same as `if(bounce==true)`

Do the same with *dflt* and *dnmm* in case you need them when are **false**

Comment: Deleting the condition doesn't really solve his problem. He wants to check if the property exist.